# Hide data areas in IDA IDC

Tags: ida

I'm using the following IDC function to copy the RAM Data and Code sections from the packed binary, into the correct runtime locations for my Fujitsu FR system:

```
static idc_memcpy(source, dest, count, desc)
{
    auto i, val;

    SetCharPrm(INF_GENFLAGS, INFFL_LOADIDC|GetCharPrm(INF_GENFLAGS));
    Message("Copy %a: Start\n", dest);

    for(i = 0; i < count; i = i + 2 )
    {
        val = Word(source + i);
        PatchWord(dest + i, val);
    }

    SetCharPrm(INF_GENFLAGS, ~INFFL_LOADIDC&GetCharPrm(INF_GENFLAGS));

    MakeUnknown(source,count,DOUNK_EXPAND+DOUNK_DELNAMES);

    HideArea(source, source+count-1, desc, "", "", -1);
    SetHiddenArea(source, 1 );
    Message("Copy %a: End\n", dest);

}
```

But when I go to the source address I see:

```
ROM:00447E8C ; [0000C878 BYTES: BEGIN OF AREA RAM Data2 Source. PRESS KEYPAD "-" TO COLLAPSE]
ROM:00447E8C unk_447E8C:     .byte 0xFF              ; DATA XREF: Tsk32+176o
ROM:00447E8D                 .byte 0xFF
ROM:00447E8E                 .byte 0xFF
ROM:00447E8F                 .byte 0xFF
ROM:00447E90                 .byte    0
ROM:00447E91                 .byte 0x30 ; 0
ROM:00447E92                 .byte    0
ROM:00447E93                 .byte    0
```

I was hoping/expecting to have that area hidden, what am I doing wrong. If I press keypad <kbd>-</kbd> I get the error message:

> IDA failed to display the program in graph mode.
>   Only instructions belonging to functions can be displayed in graph mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it after trying many things.

I had to change the data area to a byte array with

```
    MakeByte(source);
    MakeArray(source, byte_count);
```

after the `MakeUnknown`, and then call `SetHidden` with value `0`

Also to the Hiding the Area with keyboard, the new default keys are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>, the displayed text in IDA is wrong.

thus final code was:

```
static idc_memcpy(source, dest, byte_count, desc)
{
    auto i, val;

    SetCharPrm(INF_GENFLAGS, INFFL_LOADIDC|GetCharPrm(INF_GENFLAGS));
    Message("Copy %a: Start\n", dest);

    for(i = 0; i < byte_count; i = i + 2 )
    {
        val = Word(source + i);
        PatchWord(dest + i, val);
    }

    SetCharPrm(INF_GENFLAGS, ~INFFL_LOADIDC&GetCharPrm(INF_GENFLAGS));

    MakeUnknown(source,byte_count,DOUNK_EXPAND+DOUNK_DELNAMES);
    MakeByte(source);
    MakeArray(source, byte_count);

    HideArea(source, source+byte_count, desc, "", "", -1);
    SetHiddenArea(source, 0 );
    Message("Copy %a: End\n", dest);
}
```